# mysql number of blog posts by a user and display month

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

- Blogs
- Users
- User Blogs

I want to get a count of the total number of blogs for a specific user and group by the months. This works query works fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM blogs b
    INNER JOIN blog_user bu ON bu.`blog_id` = b.id 
WHERE bu.`user_id` = 1
GROUP BY
    MONTH(b.`created_at`)
```

However I want to return the month JANUARY etc.. along side the count of the total number. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MONTH(blogs.created_at)
    FROM blogs b
        INNER JOIN blog_user bu ON bu.`blog_id` = b.id 
    WHERE bu.`user_id` = 1
    GROUP BY
        MONTH(b.`created_at`)
```

However I get:

Unknown column `blogs.created_at`

Any ideas to how I can do this?

Comment: plz give the structure of yr tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aliased `blogs` table as `b`, therefore you need to refer to its columns with the `b` prefix: `MONTH(b.created_at)`

You used the right aliases across the entire sql statement, apart from this instance.